# Twitter API Set-Up Error - Twitter OAuth

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

I'm new to the twitter API and I'm trying to create an app using php. I've created the following code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once("src/TwitterOAuth.php");

    $apikey="mykey";
    $apisecret="mysecret";
    $accesstoken="mytoken";
    $accesssecret="secrettoken";

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($apikey, $apisecret, $accesstoken, $accesssecret);

    $tweets = 
    $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2");

    print_r($tweets);

?>
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/sites/crimsonroot.com/public_html/twitter/twitteroauth-master/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 334
```

I downloaded the twitter oauth from github and uploaded it to my server, so I know that the php document from the twitter oauth is correct.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: It looks like someone made a mistake while updating the library's code . Wait for an update or go and see what's going wrong with line # 334

Comment: @bader that's what I was thinking, but it looks right to me. Line 334 looks like this: if (in_array($method, ['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) && !empty($postfields)) {
            $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= '?' . Util::buildHttpQuery($postfields);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 if (in_array($method, ['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) && !empty($postfields)) { $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= '?' . Util::buildHttpQuery($postfields); }
```

With

```
 if (in_array($method, array('GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE')) && !empty($postfields)) { $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= '?' . Util::buildHttpQuery($postfields); }
```

-- I don't know why he used [] it's definitely not php syntax

-- to be sure I visited the php manual again and I was wrong this code appears as a new method to create an array and will work only for php 5.4+ . So upgrade your php or edit the unsuitable code

Comment: Thank you! I had to go and upgrade my PHP through my Cpanel and edit the .htaccess file to default to the newest PHP version.